# Como acceder a miembros de una clase con un vector de clase

Tags: c++

Tengo la clase CClass

```
//clase.h
class CClass{

public:

int suma (int X, int Y);

private:

int X;
int Y;
}

//clase.cpp

//constructor aqui

int
CClass::suma(intX, int Y){

int resultado = 0;

resultado = X + Y;

return resultado;
}
```

Y en main.cpp he creado un bloque de memoria con varios objetos de la clase CClass con la ayuda de un for y un puntero

```
//main.cpp

ifstream  fitxer(fichero);

if (fitxer.is_open())
{

   int = 0;

   delete[] m_Clase; //m_Clase es un apuntador al objeto de la clase declarado en main.h

   m_Clase = new CClass [10]; //reservo un bloque de memoria para 10 objetos CClass

   for (i=0; i<10; i++){

      is >> m_Clase[i];
   }

   fitxer.close();
}
```

Ahora quiero incluir una funcion en main.cpp para sumar el resultado de todas las funciones 'suma' de los diferentes objetos de CClass

```
int suma total(/*???*/){

int total = 0;

//total = suma() + suma() + suma ()... etc
}
```

Pero no tengo ni idea de que variables he de pasarle ni como completarla.

Comment: no deberias pasar el vector de clases?

Comment: No se como se hace eso, me lo podrias explicar porfa? Es que estoy recien empezando a aprender C++. Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

> Pero no tengo ni idea de que variables he de pasarle.

Con el código facilitado, tienes dos opciones:

#### Puntero y tamaño.

Esta aproximación es tradicional en C, e igualmente válida en C++ aunque menos usada.

```
int suma_total(const CClass *const arreglo, int tamanyo){

    int total = 0;

    for (int indice = 0; indice < tamanyo; ++indice)
        total += arreglo[índice].suma(?, ?);

    return total;
}
```

La llamada en `main` se parecería a:

```
m_Clase = new CClass [10];

// ...

int suma = suma_total(m_Clase, 10);
```

#### Puntero de inicio y de final.

Esta aproximación es tradicional en C++, e igualmente válida en C aunque menos usada.

```
int suma_total(const CClass *const inicio, const CClass *const fin){

    int total = 0;

    for (const CClass *clase = inicio; clase != fin; ++clase)
        total += clase->suma(?, ?);

    return total;
}
```

La llamada en `main` se parecería a:

```
m_Clase = new CClass [10];

// ...

int suma = suma_total(m_Clase, m_Clase + 10);
```

#### Problemas.

1. La función `suma total` está mal nombrada, C++ no permite identificadores que contengan espacios.
2. El parámetro `intX` de `CClass::suma` es incorrecto, asumo que querías `int X`.
3. Los parámetros `X` e `Y` de la función `CClass::suma` enmascaran los miembros `X` e `Y` de la clase `CClass`, usa otros nombres para los parámetros o para los miembros.
4. No se para qué usas los parámetros `X` e `Y` de la función `suma total`, ¿quieres sumar los valores de cada instancia de `CClass` o sumar valores que serán proveídos desde fuera de la clase?

---

Posiblemente te surjan más dudas tras leer esta respuesta, no dudes en formular preguntas nuevas.